# How to access any of the classes/methods from someone else's Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, require, git-submodules

I have a Rails project that needs to use someone else's Git repository in order to handle a bit of the backend work. I brought the guy's repository into my own and made it a submodule (**not sure if this was the right move)**, so I have a folder called 'submodule' within my project directory (i.e it's on the same level as my app, bin, config folders).

To require all the file functionality in the submodule folder, I put the following in my application_controller.rb (using the require_all gem):

```
  require_all 'submodule'
```

Here's my confusion: the submodule folder is a Rails app in and of itself, so it has an app folder, config, etc. I want to be able to use, ***in my application***, any of the mailers/controllers/helpers that the ***submodule folder*** uses. I know I required them correctly, but how do I properly reference these classes/methods in my application? What's the syntax for that?

For example, the submodule has a deliveries controller which includes a DeliveryProcessor class, and the DeliveryProcessor class has a method called deliver. How do I call the DeliveryProcessor class's deliver method in **my** application's controller?

Comment: Requiring all files in another rails app could have unintended consequences. For example what if your two apps are configured differently? All the submodule's configuration will be loaded into the main app. I think it'd be better to package your submodule into a gem or to mount it through rack.

Comment: You might want to look into Rails Engines